# Possible bug in GDAL?

Tags: python, gdal, grib, cdo-climate

Given this file:

http://mtarchive.geol.iastate.edu/2019/02/18/mrms/ncep/GaugeCorr_QPE_01H/GaugeCorr_QPE_01H_00.00_20190218-150000.grib2.gz

… I get different output depending on the software I use.

```
wgrib2 2019021815.grib2 -csv wgrib2.csv
```

and

```
cdo outputtab,date,time,lat,lon,value 2019021815.grib2 > cdo.txt
```

both output:

```
-3 (undefined) :  8,869,250 records
0              : 14,848,865 records
Other values   :    781,885 records
___________________________________
Total          : 24,500,000 records
```

However:

```
gdal_translate.exe -of xyz 2019021815.grib2 gdal.csv
```

outputs `-3` for all 24,500,000 records.

I get the same result if I parse the file using Python + GDAL.

Is this a bug in GDAL?  I'd like to be able to parse these files using Python.

---

I'm using Windows for wgrib2, which can be downloaded from ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/wd51we/wgrib2/Windows_7/

I'm also using Windows for GDAL, which can be downloaded from https://gdal.org/download.html

I'm using Linux for cdo, which can be downloaded from
https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I get the same -3.

Comment: @David, thanks for the confirmation that this doesn't work in GDAL.  I may make this a bounty question to get more interest.

Comment: I work with MRMS quite a bit on my own personal project. It's worth knowing (just in case) that the Weather-Climate Toolkit from NOAA can export MRMS and other gridded/radial data to CSV, json, tiff, etc. If you are ever in a pinch, check it out.

Comment: @David, I've used the Toolkit but hadn't tried exporting to CSV.  It's twice as fast as wgrib2 and provides a better output format.  And it seems to automatically exclude the undefined values.  This doesn't solve the GDAL issue, but it looks to be a better solution altogether.  If you make a post and I don't get a better answer, I'll be happy to give you the bounty!

Comment: thanks. I will do that. Hopefully we will see some other posts on this question. GDAL is a beast.

Comment: I'm assuming you're on *Win*. Could you share the tools you're using? Are there some that require a license? Did you download them or you build them? Can you share their versions?

Comment: Good questions, @CristiFati.  No license needed, and there are executables and instructions for all at the links I've now added to my post.  Latest versions.

Comment: Ok, it's what I was afraid of (regarding *gdal* - it comes as an archive from *conda* repos). And on *Win*, everything is under *Cygwin*. Will test, although my experience in this area is somewhere close to 0.

Comment: Just to add another data point: I get _correct_ results running `gdal_translate` on macOS.

Comment: Don't go to a lot of trouble.  David's solution may be the best.

Comment: Hmm, that's why I asked about the tool versions. The download *URL*s remain the same but their content is subject to change (update). I wasn't specific enough. Maybe the same *URL* will point to different versions for different platforms. @NikolasStevenson-Molnar kind of supports this. I don't know how to get *gdal* on *OSX*, but I imagine it's not from the *conda* repos. Bottom line: if it works on *OSX*, it should also work on *Win* (the same code version).

Comment: @NikolasStevenson-Molnar, interesting!  I'll see if there's an update to GDAL that fixes things, but traveling at the moment.

Comment: Sorry for being pushy, but the *gdal* download (from *conda* repos) didn't include (as expected) executables (like *gdal\_translate*). The *whl*s are available at https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal (I don't have to build them myself :) ).

Comment: @RickHitchcock I'm on version 2.4.2.

Comment: Thanks, @CristiFati.  Been a while since I did the installation, and I've been traveling so I couldn't confirm.  I actually got the Windows binaries from http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php.

Comment: @NikolasStevenson-Molnar, that version fixes the bug!  I'll probably still use David's solution, but your answer answers the question and could qualify for the bounty if you'd like to post.

Comment: Thanks, @RickHitchcock, I'll turn it into an answer.

Comment: Just as a note, I got that error using *gdal\_translate* (versions *2.4.1* and *3.0.1*). which was included in the *whl*s that I mentioned earlier. Anyway, good to hear the problem is fixed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you suggest, this seems to be a bug in GDAL. I tested the same command using GDAL 2.4.2, and it works. The [change log for 2.4.0](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/Release/2.4.0-News) points to several fixes to the GRIB driver.

> GRIB driver:
>
> - replace DataSource? and derived classes with VSILFILE directly for > 4GB file support on Windows
> - turn printf() warning as CPLDebug() messages
> - read and write missing data values correctly for complex packing when original data is integer (#1063)
> - g2clib: avoid int overflow. Fixes ​https://bugs.chromium.org/p/oss-fuzz/issues/detail?id=8194
> - g2clib: avoid potential out of bound access (CID 1393528)
> - degrib: fix floating point division by zero. Fixes ​https://bugs.chromium.org/p/oss-fuzz/issues/detail?id=9407.
> - degrib: avoid potential floating point division by zero. Fixes ​https://bugs.chromium.org/p/oss-fuzz/issues/detail?id=10291
> - add UNIT[] node to SRS on reading, so that is valid

Comment: Thank you!  The latest version does indeed fix the bug.

Answer (score 5):

My answer to your issue would be to switch to using the Weather-Climate Toolkit from NOAA.

[Download Here for Windows/Mac/Linux](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/wct/install.php)

It can export gridded and radial NEXRAD/MRMS data to CSV. A sample batch command for anyone needing this assistance would be :

```
wct-export DataSetName.grib2.gz csv Output.csv wctbatchconfig.xml
```

If it throws errors, try a different/earlier/beta version of WCT from : 
https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/wct/dist/ and be sure to check the sample commands on the website.

Comment: Even though you've provided me with a fantastic alternative, I had to give the bounty to Nikolas since he provided a direct answer to the question.  But thanks again - I'm working on an API to serve weather data (including MRMS), which you may find useful.